# $.get() in a .each() loop, get the $(this) in the $.get

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I know that my question is poorly worded but i don't know how to say it better..

I actually work with a .each() loop, and in this loop, i must change a css() parameter of the current item, but i don't success..

Here is my code:

```
$(document).find('.test').find('p').each(function(){
    var test=$(this).css('background-image').split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
    var retGet=$.get(test);
    $(this).css({
        'background-image':  'url(data:image/png;base64,'+retourGet.responseText+')'
    }); 
});
```

I removed the part of the url editing (the second line give me the actual url and i edit it).

When i use this code, i get undefined in my css parameters... It seems that when i try to change the background image, the $.get loading is not ended...

I tried to do something like this:

```
$.get( test, function( data ) {

});
```

But i don't know how to access the .each() $(this) here..

Comment: can you set a fiddle or a codepen to experiment the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the parameters from the `each` function:

```
$(document).find('.test').find('p').each(function(idx, item){
    var test=$(item).css('background-image').split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
    var retGet=$.get(test);
    $(item).css({ // item is the current .test object
        'background-image':  'url(data:image/png;base64,'+retourGet.responseText+')'
    }); 
});
```

And, in case you want to use the callback from `.get`, you could use the `item` variable:

```
$.get( test, function( data ) {
 $(item).css({ // item is the current .test object
        'background-image':  'url(data:image/png;base64,'+data+')'
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It don't work better, it seems to be something about promise(), when i try to access my data after the loop, the background is not edited yet and i see the edition 5sec after ~

Comment: that problem is related to closure or binding. Javascript is single threaded, that issues may happen when looping multiple callbacks... check for @user3508122 answer and this: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to this. First of all is to use the method described by @celerno (which is probably the preferred solution)

Second is to use function binding to set the this pointer correctly.

`$.get( test, function( data ) {
    $(this) // will now work
}.bind(this));`

Edit: The native bind method is only implemented in browsers supports ECMAScript 5 and later. So using this method wont work on older browsers. (IE8 and below I think)

Answer (score 0):

you use the i and val (the index and values) parameters of the each:

```
$(document).find('.test').find('p').each(function(i, val){
    var test=$(val).css('background-image').split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
    var retGet=$.get(test);
    $(val).css({
        'background-image':  'url(data:image/png;base64,'+retourGet.responseText+')'
    }); 
});
```

note that the function() is replaced with function(i,val) and the $(this) is replaced with $(val)  see for more info:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

(ran into this issue before - frustrated me like anything)

Answer (score 0):

Without your fiddle i cannot really  figure your problem.
But i run into something quiet similar a while ago.

you may test this : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bscaF

Comments should explain :

```
$(".test").children().each(function() {
  var domel= $(this).get(0);
  $(this).attr("data-tag",domel.nodeName);

   if ( domel.nodeName == 'P' ) {
   var test=$(this).css('background-image').split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
    var retGet=$.get(test);   
    // this.style.background = 'url(data:image/png;base64,'+retourGet.responseText+')';// does not work here out of context
    //  this.css('background','blue'); //does not work
   this.style.background = 'red';
   }
})
```